# Php code interfering with html on the footer

Tags: php, html, css

This is what's happening when I write the table manually with HTML code the footer stays in the bottom of the page where it should be, but when I do that with PHP the footer shows up in the middle of the page. Below is the PHP code I have used to print the table:

```php
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["tipi"],$_POST["godina"],$_POST["kati"]))
    {
    // Create connection
    $con=@mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","merville");// duhet ndryshuar emri i databazes dhe pastaj emri i tabeles ne rastin tone merville

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Per momentin faqja eshte duke u punuar. ";
    }
    else{


    //#################################
    

    $tipi=$_POST["tipi"];

    $godina=$_POST["godina"];

    $kati=$_POST["kati"];

    $dhoma=$_POST["dhoma"];

    //#################################



    //############ berja e querit

    $kerkim="SELECT * FROM motorrkerkimi WHERE  tipi='$tipi'
        AND godina='$godina' And kati='$kati' And dhoma='$dhoma' 
        ORDER BY vleratotale ASC";
    $query1=mysqli_query($con,$kerkim);
    //############ 
    echo "<table border='2' class='table-fill' >
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Apartamenti </th>
    <th>Dhoma </th>
    <th>Kati </th>
    <th>Sip. Totale m2 </th>
    <th>Cmimi Euro/m2 </th>
    <th>Vlera totale Euro </th>
    <th>Foto dhe Detaje </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    ";
    echo "<tbody class='table-hover'>";
    while($kerkim=mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){

            echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>"; echo "".$kerkim[1]; echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>"; echo "".$kerkim[6]; echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>"; echo "".$kerkim[4]; echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>"; echo "".$kerkim[12]; echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>"; echo "".$kerkim[10]; echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>"; echo "".$kerkim[11]; echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>"; echo "<a href='$kerkim[14]' >Shiko</a>"; echo "</td>";
                
            echo "</tr>";
            
    }
    echo "</tbody>";


        mysqli_close($con);

    }// fundi i else-it fillestar i cili ben ekzekutimin e kodit nqs databaza eshte pa probleme.
        
    }else{echo "<h2>Ju lutem plotesoni te dhenat perpara se te klikoni.</h2>";}// fundi i if-it fillestar
?>
```

Here is a photo to illustrate my problem:
[image]

The transparent gray block is the footer, and it's in the middle of the page, it doesn't stay in the bottom. If I do that only with HTML without any  PHP code, the footer stays in the end, and it doesn't interfere with the table.
Can some give me an idea, what am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: where are you trying to call this php script? I assume in the same place as when you write it in html, right?

Comment: There must be something messed up in the output of the PHP code. Does it include classes that you're not aware of? Are all of the tags closed properly? Are all of the proper classes included when the PHP runs?

Comment: missing `</table>` it looks like.

Comment: let me trie Jay Blanchard, cause I think i have done it with </table> but still no success and about the classes thing i am aware of the classes used because when i write it with html it works

Comment: yup I was wrong it looks like that when i have writen the table with html i have done it correctly but when outputing it with php I have missed that </table> thx for the feedback guys.

Answer (score 5):

```
                                                                                                        here
                                                                                                        is
                                                                                                        the

                                                                                                        a
                                                                                                        n
                                                                                                        s
                                                                                                        w
                                                                                                        e
                                                                                                        r

                                                                                                        "It appears that you haven't
                                                                                                        closed the table </table>"
```

Comment: I have found this answer so useful that I will write it into a library for use on all of my php projects. Thank you sir.

Comment: Yeah, c'mon downvoter. Tell us why this doesn't work for you.