# checkbox and ineger variable doesn't send any data to phpMyAdmin database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not sure if I actually have problem with checkbox form or age, height and weight which i put it in int as variable on phpMyAdmin. Because after I click signup, it just write error upside the form. So I really confuse where is my error

```js
<?php

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
 header("Location: home.php");
}
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_POST['signup']))
{
 $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
 $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
 $upass = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
 $age = $_POST['age'];
 $disease=$_POST['disease'];
 $weight = $_POST['weight'];
 $heigth = $_POST['height'];
 
 $dis=""; 
 $flag=0; 
 foreach($disease as $entry){ 
 $dis .= $entry."|"; 
 $flag=1; 
 } 
 if($flag==1){ 
 $dis=rtrim($dis); 
 } 

 // Insert data into mysql 
 $sql="INSERT INTO users(username,email,password, age, disease, weight, heigth) VALUES('$username','$email','$upass', '$age', '$dis', '$weight', '$heigth')";
 $result=mysql_query($sql); 

 // if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
 if($result){ 
 echo "Successful"; 
 echo "<BR>"; 
 echo "<a href='P.SIGNUP.php'>Back to main page</a>"; 
 } 

 else { 
 echo "ERROR"; }
}
?>
```

```html
<form name=register method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" onSubmit="return validatePwd()">
    <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="disease" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <h1>Register</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="User Name" class="required" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="6-12 character" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password2" placeholder="6-12 character" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">E-mail</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Someone@example.com" class="email required" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="age" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Age</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="number" name="age" min="45" max="55" step="1" value="45" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="disease" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Disease</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="disease[]" value="obesity" />Obesity<br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="disease[]" value="diabetes" />Diabetes<br/><br/>
                    <b>Cancer</b><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="disease[]" value="coloncancer" />Colon Cancer<br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="disease[]" value="kidneyCancer" />Kidney Cancer<br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="disease[]" value="breastCancer" />Breast Cancer<br/><br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="disease[]" value="cardio" />Cardio Disease<br/>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="weight" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Weight</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="number" name="weight" min="30" max="180" step="10" />kg
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="height" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Height</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="number" name="height" min="100" max="200" step="10" />cm
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="disease" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="signup"> SIGNUP </button>
                </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: In the `else` where you print `ERROR` can you print `mysql_error()` instead? Also, `height` is misspelled as `$heigth`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26169948/php-code-interfering-in-html-footer

Comment: ohh wow! thanks halcyon!!!!!